# Using AJAX POST from javascript to Rails 4 controller with Strong parameter

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm newbie with Rails

My purpose is insert `song_id` and `title` which received from Javascript via AJAX POST into Database (MySQL)

In my javascript file

```
var song_id = "23f4";
var title = "test";

$( document ).ready( function() {
jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'create',
      data: "song_id=" + song_id + "&title=" + title,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
      },
      failure: function() {
        alert("Unsuccessful");
      }
    }); 
} );
```

In my editor_controller.rb

```
class EditorController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  def create
    logger.debug("#{params[:song_id]}")
    logger.debug("#{params[:title]}")
    @song = Song.new(song_params)

    if @song.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice_song_failed] = true
      redirect_to root_path
    end 
  end

  private   
  def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:song_id, :title)
  end
```

The problem is when I running the Rails app with this code, the Console notices me that

> ActionController::ParameterMissing at /editor/create
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: song

I'm trying to use

```
private 
def song_params
  params.require(:song).permit(params[:song_id], params[:title])
end
```

but it doesn't work and notices me the same, moreover in the terminal log told me below

> Started POST "/editor/create" for ::1 at 2015-04-01 01:07:23 +0700
>
> Processing by EditorController#create as */*
>
> Parameters: {"song_id"=>"23f4", "title"=>"test"}
>
> 23f4
>
> test
>
> Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

Do I missed something in my code, Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not sending a song parameter at all.  It looks like you need to update the data line in the `jQuery.ajax` call to include the song parameter like so:

```
data: {song: {song_id: song_id, title: title}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
params.require(:song).permit(params[:song_id], params[:title])
```

is saying "require the 'song' parameter, and allow 'song_id' and 'title' through. If you don't pass a song parameter, you'll get a bad request.

You can either:

1. Change that line of code to remove the require on 'song'

or

2. Like @infused says, change your ajax call to send a song JSON object.